# Is it worth to change toner when the printer has very light print?

Tags: printer, hp-laserjet

I have an old HP Laserjet 2300dn printer which recently started to print very light print. I tried all different settings but there is not much difference. Is it likely that the toner is faulty and that buying a new one will solve this issue? Or should I change the whole printer? This question actually has some sense, because toner is quite expensive comparing to used laserjet printers on eBay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Making general assumptions here, never used that actual printeR)

There is no real way of knowing without seeing the printer.

You say old - I saw a similar issue with a old HP Laserjet, I replaced the fuser unit and it made the toner stick better and a lot darker.

However, it could just be the toner as you said, but again, without seeing, there is no real way of knowing.

Comment: Is there a reasonably easy way for me to determine if the fuser should be replaced?

Comment: It really depends on roughly how many pages you have printed since the last time it was changed, typically you know it has gone wrong because you things like this - But I have to say that I said the fuser unit because I fixed a HP Laserjet for someone with the same issue. Without seeing the printer, there really is no way of knowing as it could be almost anything.

Answer (score 2):

One quick possible easy fix if the toner is running low is to shake the toner cartridge some. Be careful though as it may release some toner while doing this. If it is just low toner, this might give you a few extra prints before having to replace it.

Like wil said, there not too much else you can change out cheaply. If you find a better deal on another used printer, that might be a better route if you don't want to try a new toner cartridge.

Comment: Tried shaking the toner, but didn't help much:( It still reports that there is 12% left though, that's why I am wondering if the problem is not with something else.

Answer (score 0):

Nice try guys but the first thing yo do if you know youre not out of toner is to go to the devices and printers folder on your computer and go to your printer and right click on it go down to properties in the window that opens look through those tabs there and see if there's someplace where it says toner save mode that will make it so your printer doesn't print very dark it's trying to save toner turn this off and your printer will print dark again you can also tell it to print all text this black instead of grey shades